# SIFT - How to deal with the pre-blurring assumption in Lowe's paper?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I'm currently trying to implement a simple version of Lowe's SIFT algorithm (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) but I have some problems with section 3.3. He describes there to use an initial sigma value of 1.6 before building up the gaussian scale space pyramid. In the next paragraph he assumes the base image to be pre-blurred with a sigma value of at least 0.5. Now I have some questions:

1. What is the background of this 0.5 pre-blurring assumption?
2. Is it now necessary to pre-blur the base image with a sigma of 0.5? E.g. the implementation of [aishack](http://www.aishack.in) ([Code](https://github.com/aishack/sift/blob/master/SIFT.cpp), Line 170) uses this approach. According to the documentation of [VLfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html) the pre-blurring with 0.5 is not needed.
3. [VLfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html) describes to calculate the sigma values with something like `sqrt(sigma^2 - sigma_initial^2)` and `sigma_intial = 0.5` to take into account the 0.5 pre-blurring. If this is the correct approach, why is it possible to simply subtract the two variances? When I remember correctly that is the case if two gaussians\pdfs are completely independent. Is this the true when dealing with pre-blurring?

Thanks in advance

Vaniax